# Laravel not detecting environemnt correct

Tags: php, laravel-4, development-environment, database-migration

I'm new to Laravel and I'd like some help please.

First of all I tried to set up my 'development' environment according to the machine name, so I did this

```
die(gethostname()); // output the machine name, in my case is ΛΥΚΟΣ-PC
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('ΛΥΚΟΣ-PC'),

));
```

but didn't seem to work. So I followed the instructions on [Environment Configuration](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration) and did the following

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){

    switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
        case 'localhost':
            return 'local';
        break;

        default:
            return 'production';
        break;
    }
});
die($env); // outputs 'local'
```

The problem is that when I tried to do some migrations, I typed in the command line:

```
$ php artisan migrate
```

in order to create the table, but I get this

```
*******************************
*  Application in Production! *
*******************************

Do you really want to run this command?
```

and if I proceed I get 'Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge'.

Well, I guess this problem has to do with the environtment configuration. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Try doing it with the `--env` flag (so `php artisan --env migrate`). Does that work?

Comment: I get the following: [RuntimeException] Not enough arguments

Comment: It should be: `php artisan migrate --env=local`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` solution doesn't work with Artisan is that `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` variable is only available when launched through a web server.

`'local' => array('ΛΥΚΟΣ-PC')` should work, might have something to do with the special characters.

I set my environment based on the laravel path:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => strpos(getcwd(), '/local')>-1,
    'staging' => strpos(getcwd(), '/staging')>-1,

));
```

So the environment is set to local if `/local` is part of the path. **Note:** You might have to replace `/` with `\` on Windows.

You can also specify the environment to Artisan:

```
php artisan migrate --env=local
```

But I would recommend you have your environments in order, makes everything easier. And less chance of messing up your production.

Comment: I tried your way and did this 'local' => strpos(getcwd(), '/htdocs/my_projects')>-1, but when I die($env); I get 'production' on screen

Comment: Hm, what does `getcwd()` contain?

Comment: my bad, sorry. I had to change '/' to '\' instead

Comment: I didn't think of that, I'm using Linux. I have that information to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to always include the environment explicitly when using an artisan command. You can do that like this:

```
php artisan migrate --env=local
```

This will ensure that the command is run in the `local` environment.

Comment: Why is this best practise? Will you still get a warning of you are on a production server?

Comment: It is best practice because if you specify the environment explicitly, you are 100% sure on which environment you are executing the command, and you won't accidentally execute a command on the wrong environment. You will still get the warning on production.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine like this, however I'd like to ask whether its possible to fix this issue with the 'local' => array('ΛΥΚΟΣ-PC') setting